Unable to set my app log level to debug, is my log4j2.properties even being read?
I am trying to initialize log4j2 in my servlet application (apache-tomcat 9).
This code
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class) ;
...
Enumeration enumerator = LogManager.getLoggerRepository().getCurrentLoggers() ;
while(enumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println("Logger ->"+((Logger)enumerator.nextElement()).getLevel().toString()) ;
}
enumerator = LogManager.getLoggerRepository().getCurrentLoggers() ;
while(enumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println("Logger ->"+((Logger)enumerator.nextElement()).getName().toString()) ;
}

prints the below on the console
Logger ->ERROR
Logger ->DEBUG
Logger ->my.package.first.MyClass
Logger ->root

In my code I have the log4j2.properties in this folder

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/

This is my log4j2.properties content
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to Console
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Console

# Console appender configuration
log4j.appender.Console.type=Console
log4j.appender.Console.name=STDOUT
log4j.appender.Console.layout.type=PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n



# Define appenders
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = CONSOLE
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %highlight{%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue}

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = FILE
appender.file.fileName = logs/application.log
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n

# Define loggers
rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = CONSOLE
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = FILE

logger.my.package.first.name = my.package.first
logger.my.package.first.level = DEBUG
logger.my.package.first.appenderRef.file.ref = FILE

logger.my.package.second.name = my.package.second
logger.my.package.second.level = DEBUG
logger.my.package.second.appenderRef.file.ref = FILE

My src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml has the following content
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>log4j2.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j2.debug</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j2.verbose</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j.shutdownHookEnabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

I have downloaded the following files and copied it to the tomcat/lib folder

log4j-web-2.24.0
log4j-core-2.24.0
log4j-api-2.24.0
log4j-jul-2.24.0

I have referred to many links on SO

One link hinted that unable to find log4j2.properties file, so I copied log4j2.properties to lib, conf, webapps, webapps/myapp, webapps/myapp/classes folders and checked, no luck same error
Other links hinted that content may in incorrect

Why is my log4j2.properties not picking up Debug for my.package?

The property would be log4j2.configurationFile afaik. But what would be reading those context-params and how?

I had to make 3 corrections

remove the log4j2.properties file from the WEB-INF folder and place it in the webapp folder. So that it shows up in my tomcat/webapps/myapp folder directly
I had to change my log4j2.properties

from
logger.my.package.first.name = my.package.first
logger.my.package.first.level = DEBUG
logger.my.package.first.appenderRef.file.ref = FILE

logger.my.package.second.name = my.package.second
logger.my.package.second.level = DEBUG
logger.my.package.second.appenderRef.file.ref = FILE

to
logger.myPackageFirst.name = my.package.first
logger.myPackageFirst.level = DEBUG
logger.myPackageFirst.appenderRef.file.ref = FILE

logger.myPackageSecond.name = my.package.second
logger.myPackageSecond.level = DEBUG
logger.myPackageSecond.appenderRef.file.ref = FILE

this answer helped me, between logger and name there should only be oneWord
Also my WEB-INF/web.xml looks like this now..
<web-app ....>
...
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher> <!-- Servlet 3.0 w/ disabled auto-initialization only; not supported in 2.5 -->
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>log4j2.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j2.debug</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j2.verbose</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j.shutdownHookEnabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

Edit

I did not need the 4 jar files in the lib folder of tomcat. Getting the 4 jars in my maven pom dependencies were enough.

